# Nested menu bar display

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem with a nested menu bar. How do I make it always appear on-screen when the browser is started or resized?

```
$('.item').mouseover(function(){
        var ul=$(this).children('ul');
        ul.css("visibility","visible");
        var heigh=$(window).height()-ul.offset().top;

        if(heigh < 600){
           ul.offset({ top: heigh-500});
        }
    });
```

jsfiddle.net/srontopekok/qJR4n/3 i want the sub menu not off screen to the bottom and stay still. look a like tmall.com

Comment: do u want to always show this menu as it appears when `mouseover` ??

Comment: As a side note, you have multiple errors in your code with `heigh` being used instead of `height`. Try fixing that first and also post your HTML and styles for the menu as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
//trigger immediately
$('.item').trigger('mouseover');

//trigger on resize
$(window).on('resize', function () { $('.item').trigger('mouseover'); });
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/srontopekok/qJR4n/3/

i want the sub menu not off screen to the bottom and stay still. look a like tmall.com